# Navigation app lost after updating phone

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation

I lost the Navagation app that came with my phone after updating the phone's system. None of the free apps on Google Play work well for me. Any clues on how to get it back? It is not on Google Play.

Comment: What phone are you using? What did you update your phone to? Is it using stock ROM, or custom ROM? Please edit these details into your question.

Comment: If you're talking about Google Navigation (the blue arrow), then it comes with Google Maps.

Answer (score 10):

The [latest Google Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en) app has the navigation function in-built. The navigation "app" was always integrated into Maps. The blue icon was just a separate entry point into that maps.

If you select a destination, look at the bottom of the screen where it says navigate and you will recognize what comes up next.

[image: S.Cap]  [image]

Comment: What if I do not want to select a destination? What if I just want to see where I am as I drive? Older "Navigation" app simple had "Show map" option that did just that (and it was different from showing static location on the map - it did show dynamic location, similar to navigation, but without destination)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter it's there at your bottom right. :) See the `target` icon? touch it and it'll show your current location.

Answer (score -2):

Update -- This morning I went to look for my familiar blue triangle and it was gone AGAIN!  I found out that you have to go into the Google Play app on your phone.  Tap on the top right icon for options.  Then click settings.  Then click on the Auto-update apps.  Then select Do not auto-update apps. Do this first, then the steps below...

Go to settings, apps, and google maps.

Click the uninstall updates.

It will give you a warning about all updates will be removed.

Click yes.

Open maps like normal.

Close maps and go back to your normal all applications, and navigation is back!

Comment: You want to roll back all app updates just because the icon is missing? Navigation is integrated tightly into the Maps app and it's easy to get to.

Comment: Stopping auto app updating is only bandaging the problem.